# Putting stuff into date ranges in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, pivot

I have a table with week ranges (week number,start date, end date) and a table with tutorial dates (for writing tutors (tutor ID, tutorial_date, tutorial type(A or B).

I want to create two query that shows the week ranges (week 1, week 2) across the top with the tutor names on the side with count of tutorials (of type "A") in that week's date range in each block for that week.

The result should look like this:

Counts of Tutorials of Type "A"

```
Tutor|Week One|Week Two|Week Three|Week Four|Total
Joe  |   3    |   5    |    7     |    8    | 23        
Sam  |   2    |   4    |    3     |    8    | 17
```

Meaning that Joe completed 3 tutorials in week one, five in week two, 7 in week three, and 8 in week 4.

The second query should show totals for tutorial type "A" and type "B"

```
Tutor|Week One|Week Two|Week Three|Week Four|Total   |
Joe  |  3/1   |   5/3  |   7/2    |   8/2   | 23/8   |     
Sam  |  2/3   |   4/4  |   3/2    |   8/3   | 17/12  |
```

Here, in Week One, Joe has done 3 tutorials of type A and 1 of type B.

Sample table data for tutorials (week one)

```
Tutor | Tutorial_ID | Tutorial Date |Type|
------------------------------------------
Joe   |    1        | 2011-01-01    | A  |
Joe   |    2        | 2011-01-02    | A  |
Joe   |    3        | 2011-01-03    | A  |
Joe   |    4        | 2011-01-03    | B  |
Sam   |    5        | 2011-01-01    | A  |
Sam   |    6        | 2011-01-02    | A  |
Sam   |    7        | 2011-01-03    | B  |
```

The week table looks like this:

```
weekNumber |startDate |endDate
1          |2011-01-01|2011-01-15
```

I'd like to gen this in SQL Server 2005

Comment: so, why does WeekNumber 1 has a date range of two weeks?...is this to be expected on your data?....or you can rely on the week of the year that the date is on?

Comment: My week date ranges are hardcoded because of business rules.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this.

For **query one**, where you only need to `PIVOT` on type 'A' then you can do just a `PIVOT`

```
select *
from 
(
  select w1.tutor
    , w1.type
    , wk.weeknumber
  from w1
  inner join wk
    on w1.tutorialdate between wk.startdate and wk.enddate
  where w1.type = 'a'
) x
pivot
(
  count(type)
  for weeknumber in ([1])
)p
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f4d6/4) with Demo

Or you can use a `Count()` with a `CASE` statement.

```
select w1.tutor
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN w1.type = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE null END) [Week One]
from w1
inner join wk
  on w1.tutorialdate between wk.startdate and wk.enddate
group by w1.tutor
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f4d6/26)

But for the **second query**, I would just use a `Count()` with a `CASE`

```
select w1.tutor
  , Cast(COUNT(CASE WHEN w1.type = 'A' AND wk.weeknumber = 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as varchar(10))
     + ' / '
     + Cast(COUNT(CASE WHEN w1.type = 'B' AND wk.weeknumber = 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as varchar(10)) [Week One]
   , Cast(COUNT(CASE WHEN w1.type = 'A' AND wk.weeknumber = 2 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as varchar(10))
     + ' / '
     + Cast(COUNT(CASE WHEN w1.type = 'B' AND wk.weeknumber = 2 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as varchar(10)) [Week Two]
from w1
inner join wk
  on w1.tutorialdate between wk.startdate and wk.enddate
group by w1.tutor
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea99e/3)

Edit as AndriyM pointed out the second could be done with a PIVOT here is a solution for the Second query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  select distinct w1.tutor
    , wk.weeknumber
    , left(total, len(total)-1) Totals
  FROM w1
  inner join wk
      on w1.tutorialdate between wk.startdate and wk.enddate
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT cast(count(w2.type) as varchar(max)) + ' / '
    from w1 w2
    inner join wk wk2
      on w2.tutorialdate between wk2.startdate and wk2.enddate
    WHERE w2.tutor = w1.tutor
      AND wk2.weeknumber = wk.weeknumber
    group by w2.tutor, wk2.weeknumber, w2.type
    FOR XML PATH('')
  )  D ( total )
)  x
PIVOT
(
  min(totals)
  for weeknumber in ([1], [2])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea99e/43)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but it seems you are not distinguishing between weeks in your CASE queries. And the OP's second query could also use PIVOT.

Comment: @AndriyM you are correct, this has been fixed.  The second query will now show the totals by date.

Comment: @AndriyM thanks for the challenge of saying the second could be done with a `PIVOT`, I have edited my answer to include a `PIVOT` for the second query.

Comment: Great job employing FOR XML! I also made an attempt to adapt your original PIVOT query for the second requirement, but couldn't come up with anything better than a double PIVOT solution. In case you are curious, please [check it out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea99e/45).

Comment: I was stumped with the PIVOT on the second one that is why I went with the CASE statements. Thanks for challenging me to do it with a PIVOT.  Very nice double PIVOT example I could not figure out how to do it that way.